# Introductory Statistics RStudio query

Tags: r, statistics, confidence-interval, variance

First time here. I'm taking an introductory statistics class which uses R. I have a dataset of 54 observations and I have to determine the 90% upper bounded confidence interval of the variance of the content. From that I have to deduce if it is possible to claim that with confidence at least 90%, is the variance of the content less than 0.001?

From my understanding I have to use the script:

```
sigma.test(data,alternative="less",conf.level=0.90)$conf.int
```

From running it, I'm getting a value of 0. That doesn't sound normal at all. I'm not sure if I'm following the correct procedures.

I would appreciate any feedback to help my understanding of this more.

Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure you get just 0? conf.int should contain two values.

Comment: Which library are you using for `sigma.test()`?